# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'sharedKeyCredential') when we try to create SAS Uri using GenerateSasUri() method with V12

Tags: c#, azure, storage, azure-managed-identity

We are migrating the code to use azure storage v12 client libraries (Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.12.0) from V11.  Getting the below mentioned exception when we try to create SAS Uri using GenerateSasUri() method.
Exception: "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'sharedKeyCredential')"

```
this.blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(
                new Uri($https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}),
                new ManagedIdentityCredential(managedIdentityAppId));

var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new()
            {
                BlobContainerName = containerName,
                BlobName = blobName,
                Resource = "b", 
                StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
                ExpiresOn = expirationTimeUtc
            };
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(requestedPermission);            

            return blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
```

Comment: You can't create SAS without using the access key. It is use to sign the Uri. So with managed identity it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You CAN create SAS Uris for AD authenticated (incl managed service identities) users as well, with what is called **user delegation key**.

Read more from here:
[Create a user delegation SAS for a container, directory, or blob with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet)

Example code (abbreviated from the link above):

```
var blobServiceClient = blobClient
    .GetParentBlobContainerClient()
    .GetParentBlobServiceClient();

var userDelegationKey = await blobServiceClient
    .GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7));

var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
{
    BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
    BlobName = blobClient.Name,
    Resource = "b",
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
};

sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

var blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
{
    Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(
            userDelegationKey, 
            blobServiceClient.AccountName)
};

var uri = blobUriBuilder.ToUri();
```

Note that user delegation keys cannot be as long-lived as shared keys. I think the max duration for UDK was in the scale of days or a few weeks, while you could use months for SAS urls with shared keys.

Answer (score 2):

Thomas pointed out the cause for this issue. The best to handle in your code is to check whether your `blobclinet` can able to create the sas using [`CanGenerateSasUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.cangeneratesasuri?view=azure-dotnet)

```
this.blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(
                new Uri($https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}),
                new ManagedIdentityCredential(managedIdentityAppId));

var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    // Check whether this BlobClient object has been authorized with Shared Key.
    if (blobClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
    {
        
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new()
            {
                BlobContainerName = containerName,
                BlobName = blobName,
                Resource = "b", 
                StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
                ExpiresOn = expirationTimeUtc
            };
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(requestedPermission);            

            return blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"BlobClient must be authorized with Shared Key 
                          credentials to create a service SAS.");
        return null;
    }
```