# Use DefaultAzureCredential for DataLakeServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I have an api that grants sas tokens to callers to upload files to blob storage. I would like to get this working with the DefaultAzureCredential.

This is the code in my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(azureBuilder => 
{
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    azureBuilder.UseCredential(credential);
    azureBuilder.AddDataLakeServiceClient(new Uri("https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/"));
});
```

And this is how i generate the sas uri:

```
        public string GenerateSasUri(string containerName) 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(containerName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(containerName));

            var permissions = DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions.Add 
                | DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions.Write
                | DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions.Create
                | DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions.List;

            return _dataLakeServiceClient
                .GetFileSystemClient(containerName)
                .GenerateSasUri(permissions, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15))
                .AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

But i am getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'sharedKeyCredential')'
```

Upon inspection of the properties on the DataLakeServiceClient, i see that the _dataLakeServiceClient.CanGenerateAccountSasUri property is false?

Did i misunderstand some things? Is this not supposed to work?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236755/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-sharedkeycredential-when-we-try-to-create-sa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're authenticating using Azure AD you cannot create a service SAS, instead you can only create a *user delegation* SAS.

See this article on how to create a user delegation SAS for a blob: [Create a user delegation SAS for a blob with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet?tabs=packages-dotnetcli#create-a-user-delegation-sas-for-a-blob).